# How to link mobile push engagement data with the journey's sent through?

Tags: journeybuilder, reporting, mobilepush, push-notification, push

In order to report on the Push message engagement we are extracting the [mobile push detail extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5). However, we currently don't have any fields in the extract that can help us link the mobile push data to the journey it was sent through. We have the message name however we are unable to link it to journey names. Since multiple journey's can have the same message name is there a way I can connect the journey and messages for reporting purposes?

Comment: The report has a PushJobId field; unfortunately this field cannot be used to link to Journey data views

Comment: @DucLe - Exactly! What is the point of the PushJobId field? Is there nothing else we can use in order to link Push messages to the journeys?

Comment: Regarding [SF document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_push_message_detailed_report.htm&type=5), PushJobId is the ID of the job to use when troubleshooting with support. And I don't see any ways to link to journeys through the report.

Comment: @DucLe - Thanks! Would you know any other way of linking push engagement data with journey's?